# Prove that the convolution of $f$ and $g$ in $C^1[-\pi, \pi]$ if either $f$ or $g$ in $C^1[-\pi, \pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Prove that the convolution of $f$ and $g$ in $C^1[-\pi, \pi]$ if either $f$ or $g$ in $C^1[-\pi, \pi]$. Here, $C^1$ is the space of all continuously differentiable functions. [Here we obtain the same for $C^0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209454/how-to-show-that-if-f-or-g-is-continuous-then-the-convolution-f-star-g-o)

But, I am not sure how to proceed for $C^1$ space. Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you also considering functions on  $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I have edited the question!

Comment: You re also again assuming that $f,g\in L^1[-\pi,\pi]$ only? Or can you assume that the two of them is continuous?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes!

Answer (score 1):

I'll give my suggestion:

As stated by @Davide Giraudo in the post you linked to, you know that $f\star g= g\star f$, so we can assume without loss of generality that $f\in C^1$.

Using  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) version of Leibniz intergral rule, we obtain that

$$\frac{d }{d x}\big[ f\star g \big] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \big[ g(y) \cdot f(x-y) \big]dy= $$

$$=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi g(y)\cdot f'(x-y)dy $$

which is continuous using the related post since $f'\in C^0$. You do have to note that $f,f'\in L^\infty$ since they are continuous on a compact set.